# The road not taken, or should a GM allow replays?

Tags: gm-techniques, new-gm

Some people say adventures are supposed to be unique experiences that cannot be recreated. What if the player wants to replay the same thing from the beginning, but try a different fork in the road? Should GMs allow players to do that?

One thing that distinguishes tabletop gaming from computer gaming is its spontaneous nature. If you're retreading old territory, it's kind of taking away from that.

But if a GM is inclined to allow the replaying of an adventure, should the player be allowed to use the same character and keep all his previous XP and loot? Or perhaps allow the same character but start with nothing? Or perhaps only allow completely new characters?

Comment: This looks like it could be a very interesting question, but I feel like it probably needs a bit of fine-tuning to fit [our guidelines on subjective questions](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3204). In particular, I'd suggest tweaking the phrasing where it seems to be asking for personal preferences or opinions (e.g. "would you […]") or unsubstantiable guesswork ("do GM's typically […]"). Also, your last sentence (about XP and loot) seems to be asking a different, more specific question. I'd suggest making it clearer which one is actually your main question here.

Comment: I edited it. How does one go about getting a question reopened?

Comment: @BladePoint Reopening requires 5 users to vote to reopen (you're on one so need another 4), they will do so if they think it is now answerable.

Comment: As for this question; "should GM allow X?" isn't really a question and more of a discussion prompt, there is no answer which isn't just an opinion. Have your players asked to do this? Do you have any concerns for why it wouldn't work, or are you trying to figure out how to do it? Perhaps in general, why are you asking this? It may be that the actual problem is addressable via a different question. You may wish to read this meta: [We should talk about the word "should"](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9344/52137), and/or open a question workshop.

Comment: @RichardC [Please don't answer in comments](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6533/14878).